# Is There a List of TensorFlow Ops that Are Supported for CPU?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to run a model which had been written for GPU on a CPU, and have discovered that the `tf.nn.bias_add` function does not support a `data_format` attribute of "NCHW" when executing on CPU, it only supports "NHWC".

Is there a list of which operations, like this one, are restricted to GPU?  I haven't been able to find one yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such list and sadly documentation does not tell these details either.

There was an attempt to ask for documentation improvement [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2502), but it does not look like it was implemented.